# Select field by next month(char6)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to select a value of field `State` for next month.
Field `Month` is char(6). Ex: `201310`.

This is what I have and it doesn't work:

`SELECT   Code, Name,
                    (SELECT   State
                     FROM      dbo.ShiftList
                     WHERE   (MONTH(CONVERT(Date, Month)) = MONTH(GETDATE()) + 1)) AS SLNM
FROM      dbo.Shops`

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: any specific error you are getting?

Comment: Error Message: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: ... I really wish people would stop storing 'formatted' numbers like this (and the fact that the OP probably only wants the current year too doesn't help any).  Is there no actual date field here?  This sounds like a prime thing to add to a calendar file, actually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the performance issues it's rather perform manipulations with variables and not with data in the table. In this case your query can be like the following:

```
SELECT
  Code,
  Name,
  (SELECT State
   FROM dbo.ShiftList 
   WHERE MONTH = cast(year(dateadd(month, 1, getdate())) * 100
                + month(dateadd(month, 1, getdate())) as char(6))
) AS SLNM
FROM dbo.Shops
```

This construction makes possible the index usage.

Comment: Yes, this should work, although it's always best to limit the number of duplicate operations if possible (for future maintenance issues, if nothing else).

Comment: Sure, the best solution was to store into the variable the needed value of the Month column (or, even, State value) and use it in the query. But, from another point, the value of the month will be calculated once per the whole query.

Answer (score 2):

Both the current answers have one major problem - the functions they call on the columns means that indices will (very likely) be ignored.  I prefer a SARGable condition, thank you:

```
SELECT state
FROM dbo.ShiftList 
WHERE month = FORMAT(DATEADD(month, 1, GETDATE()), 'yyyyMM')
```

(Have a [SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/04e65/7) - a specific date is being used for future so the example still works in the future.)
However, this only works in SQL Server 2012.  For previous versions, you'll need a slightly different version:

```
SELECT state
FROM dbo.ShiftList 
WHERE month = CONVERT(CHAR(6), DATEADD(month, 1, CAST('20131201' as date)), 112)
```

(...and the relevant [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/04e65/6))

Note that there is one potential problem with this - the optimizer may decide to call this subquery for *every* row in the final result set.  Without more information about your tables and data, we can't tell if there's some way to improve the overall query, though.

Comment: how can we know when indices will be ignored ?? i am asking what should we need to see while writing .. i think we can know that from execution plan that whether indices will be ignored .. but i am asking while writing what should we take care so that indices will not be ignored ??

Comment: Right, you can only actually guarantee that an index has been ignored by checking the explain plan.  Still, some educated guesses can be made through the simple question - "Is the _unmodified start_ of the column an output of the function?"; a smart optimizer can actually probably use an index for something like `WHERE SUBSTR(dbCol, 1, 3) = 'YES'` (it won't necessarily run the `SUBSTR()` function - just stops the comparison after three characters)...

Comment: This is more subtle than initially appears, though, because date/time/timestamp types aren't actually stored 'in format' (usually as a count), so _any_ function on those types needs to interpret them first, meaning anything but comparisons between values is likely to toss the index.  And numbers have something of the same problem, because the digit representation we think of isn't how the computers deal with them (ie, dividing by 100 isn't actually "getting the 'start'" of a number)... so in general, it's best to call functions on the _starting_ data, and compare to the raw data in the column.

Answer (score 0):

If you have fixed format in field 'month' as 'YYYYMM' then you can fetch year and month as:

```
select RIGHT([Month],2) AS MONTH ,LEFT([Month],4) AS YEAR
FROM dbo.ShiftList
```

and get required 'State' values as:

```
SELECT [State] 
 FROM dbo.ShiftList 
 WHERE  RIGHT([Month],2) = MONTH(DATEADD(month, 1, GETDATE())) 
 AND LEFT([Month],4) = YEAR(DATEADD(month, 1, GETDATE()))
```

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse..Thanks for pointing that out. Corrected my solution.

Comment: Manipulation with data from the column will avoid the index usage what must be resulted as low query performnace.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT Code, Name, (SELECT State FROM dbo.ShiftList WHERE (MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, Month / 100 * 12 - 22800 + Month % 100, -1))) = MONTH(GETDATE()) + 1)) AS SLNM FROM dbo.Shops
```

I havent checked it though.

Comment: ...And it still doesn't work (given that `DATEADD()` is returning a `datetime` or similar type, and is being compared against an integer, I'm surprised it's not actually throwing an error.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse i have missed MONTH over DATEADD. i have updated.

Comment: You still technically have syntax errors in the statement (check parenthesis count, please).  Selects all instances of the 'next' month (ie - November this year, last year, etc); this is _potentially_ what the OP is going for (given he was a little vague on this part), although I feel it somewhat unlikely.